# How do I find which activiti script is causing an error?

Tags: activiti

I'm using the activiti workflow engine and I'm getting an error due to a type in a logging statement.  I have looked in every script that I remember putting a logging statement in, but I can't find anything amiss.  I'm new to activiti, so it is also possible that there is a flaw in my basic understanding of how activiti works here.

Here's my error:

```
{
  "header": {
    "sessionId": null,
    "errors": [
      {
        "code": "INTERNAL_ERROR",
        "message": "Unexpected error occurred.",
        "messageDetailed": "Error starting process: mock_process\nCaused by: problem evaluating script: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:\nScript143.groovy: 20: expecting ')', found 'loggerlinfo' @ line 20, column 1.\n   loggerlinfo(logMap) \n   ^\n\n1 error\n",
        "moreInfo": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I can see that the invalid "loggerlinfo(logMap" is causing the problem.  That is a typo from what should have been "logger.info(logMap)".  I know where the "mock_process" is in the workflow, but it calls several scripts and also subprocesses within itself that have their own scripts.  I've looked through manually and I can't find this error anywhere.

So I understand the error, I just can't find the script that it is referring to.  Can I somehow find the script based on Script143.groovy?  Or can I search through all of the scripts for the typo by text search?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Process debugger could help you to find the error too:
https://gromar01.wordpress.com/2017/03/28/process-debugging-user-interface/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activiti processes are just XML so I often open up notepad++, use ctrl+f and choose the find in files tab and search for your text in the parent folder containing all your processes. Obviously be careful editing the XML directly but this should help you find the problem script.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I had no idea they were even stored as XML.  I found the scripts (stored in a database in my case), but I would never have even thought of looking there without this help.

Comment: No problem, glad you sorted it.

Comment: The problem you are experiencing isn't specifically in your XML.
Your process isn't starting because there is an error in a script that is either defined in a script task or as a listener associated with the start event. Appears to be a syntax error.